# Syntax for executing unslick() on responsive breakpoint

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Can someone explain to me where I place unslick() in the code - I want to turn off the slick slider on the lowest breakpoint (phones), but remain on ipads and desktops.

I can see that Ken specifys how to use it - but I'm new to JS and don't know where to enter what he is describing.

Thanks,

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have unslick at breakpoint 480 you would do it like this:

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: "unslick"
    }
  ]
});
```